# Chat app Using Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to build an chat app using firebase  i have a probleme in the firebase recyclerview adapter  it shows this error

Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String

my structure User -> IDuser -> Chat -> id chat - > messages -> id message

Chat contain all the deffrente conversations of the the user

my code :

```
    @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(Cuid).child("Chat").child(idconvC).child("messages").getRef();
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Message> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Message>()
                    .setQuery(query,Message.class)
                    .build();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Message,Conv.ConvViewHolder>
            (options) {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Conv.ConvViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            // Create a new instance of the ViewHolder, in this case we are using a custom
            // layout called R.layout.message for each item
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.messagerow, parent, false);
            return new Conv.ConvViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder (@NonNull Conv.ConvViewHolder viewHolder,final int position,@NonNull Message model) {

            if (model.getUsername().equals(Cusername)) {
            viewHolder.seturi(getApplicationContext(),model.getUri());
            viewHolder.setusername(model.getUsername());
            viewHolder.setmsg(model.getMessage());
            viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d3d3d3"));
                // Gravity right

            }
            else {
                viewHolder.seturi(getApplicationContext(),model.getUri());
                viewHolder.setusername(model.getUsername());
                viewHolder.setmsg(model.getMessage());
                // Gravity left
                }

            }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
    }
```

my database :[image]

Comment: I can't see your databse structure

Comment: I have just uploaded another Picture of the database

Comment: Have you tried to remove `getRef()` from your query?

Comment: yes i tried it doesn"t work :(